# Need to get correct planetary longitude correct from Swiss ephemeris in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code that try to convert a specific Date/Time (in UT) to TROPICAL HELIOCENTRIC longitude of a planet (in this case, Jupiter and Saturn) but it gives the wrong result whenever I try to display both,it got correctly only when one of them is displayed

As you can see , I have to put a comment sign on one of the 2 lines calculating saturn and jupiter's longitude (swe_calc_ut function) ,otherwise it would give wrong calculation

```vb
Sub ComputeHelioLongitudes()
  Dim julian_UT As Double
  
    Dim saturnLong As Double, jupiterLong As Double
    Dim flag As Integer
    Dim errBuff As String
   
    
    
    Dim dateTimeValue As Date
    Dim yearValue As Integer
    Dim monthValue As Integer
    Dim dayValue As Integer
    Dim hourValue As Integer
    Dim minuteValue As Integer
    Dim total_hour_Value As Double
    Dim minuteValue_in_hour As Double
    
        

    ' Extract Components
    yearValue = year(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value)
    monthValue = month(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value)
    dayValue = day(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value)
    hourValue = hour(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value)
    minuteValue = Minute(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value)
    
    
    minuteValue_in_hour = minuteValue / 60
    
    total_hour_Value = hourValue + minuteValue_in_hour
    
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 2) = yearValue
    Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) = monthValue
    Sheet1.Cells(3, 2) = dayValue
    Sheet1.Cells(4, 2) = total_hour_Value
   

'FORMULA TO CALCULATE JULIAN DAYS

 julian_UT = swe_julday(yearValue, monthValue, dayValue, total_hour_Value, SE_GREG_CAL)
 Sheet1.Cells(6, 2) = julian_UT
    
 
       

    ' --- Flags for Tropical and Heliocentric ---
    flag = SEFLG_SWIEPH + SEFLG_HELCTR + SEFLG_TRUEPOS + SEFLG_J2000

    ' --- Calculations (with longitude output variables) ---

    Call swe_calc_ut(julian_UT, SE_SATURN, flag, saturnLong, errBuff)
  ' Call swe_calc_ut(julian_UT, SE_JUPITER, flag, jupiterLong, errBuff)

    ' --- Display Results ---

    Sheet1.Cells(3, 17) = jupiterLong
    Sheet1.Cells(4, 17) = saturnLong
  
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `swe_calc_ut`? Is it using `byref` for `julian_UT`, `flag`, or `errBuff`, where perhaps those variables are getting modified before they can be used to calculate `JUPITER`? When both are ran, is saturn always correct and jupiter is always wrong?

Comment: swe_calc_ut is a function to calculate planetary position, this is written from doc documenation as followed:            int32 swe_calc_ut(
double tjd_ut,
int32 ipl,
int32 iflag,
double* xx,
char* serr);
where
tjd_ut = Julian day, Universal Time
ipl = body number
iflag = a 32 bit integer containing bit flags that indicate what kind of computation is wanted
xx = array of 6 doubles for longitude, latitude, distance, speed in long., speed in lat., and speed in dist.
serr[256]= character string to return error messages in case of error.

Comment: when both are ran, they are both incorrect, if only one of them is ran then it is correct

Comment: Any particular reason using the integer type?  Preferable use the long type see  [why-use-integer-instead-of-long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)